# DBI: are schema and table-name enough for a qualified table name?

Tags: perl, dbi, identifier

Are there cases where a qualified table name consisting of schema and table-name, is not sufficient if the connection was made with the `DBI` `connect` method?
Not sufficient in the sense that the catalog in the qualified table name would also be required.

Connect could look like this:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:$sdriver:$db", ... );

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:$sdriver:dbname=$db", ... );
```

The '...' could be one or more of: host, port, user, password and attributes.

For these drivers: `DBD::SQLite`, `DBD::mysql`, `DBD::MariaDB`, `DBD::Pg`, `DBD::Firebird`, `DBD::DB2` and `DBD::Informix`.

It is used in [App::DBBrowser](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::DBBrowser).

Comment: Perhaps give us more info like the database type and what the dbi connect looks like?

Comment: I think this belongs on the [DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  I believe you are asking, is it possible to connect to any of these seven databases in a way that makes resolving a `schema.table_like_object` in a subsequent query ambiguous?  (And further, is this scenario exposed in the perl DBD bindings atop the databases' SDKs?)  I'd be keen to understand any "yes" answer to that question, but I think it best answered elsewhere.

Comment: In DBD::SQLite, DBD::mysql, DBD::MariaDB, DBD::Pg I think your good. I dont work in the others.